# Wordpress Рубрика с постами

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите по Wordpress:

**Как сделать следующее?:**

1. Вывести рубрики с подпостами
2. Если в рубрике всего лишь один пост, то сразу же его раскрыть (полная часть)

**Сейчас:**

1. Рубрики выводятся без подпостов
2. Если в рубрике один пост, то пост выводится в сокращенном виде (и кнопка читать далее)

**Хочу сделать как на картинке:**
1- Рубрика с одним постом (при нажатии открывается полный пост, без читать далее)
2- Рубрика, которе содержит подпосты
3- Подпосты

Как на этом фото:
[image: деловой кот]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Изображения должны быть в теле вопроса. Исправь.

Comment: @SeVlad благодарю